# regex - how to negate multiple words

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have html pages in the root directory of my website, and more pages in a folder called "c".

I have the following regex in my .htaccess file to hide the subdirectory "**/c**" from the url.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(a|c|e|f|i|n|s|home|mainpage1|mainpage2| mainpage3|mainpage4|mainpage5|mainpage6|mainpage7|mainpage8|mainpage9|mainpage10|mainpage11|mainpage12|mainpage13|mainpage14|mainpage15)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /c/$1 [NC,L]
```

Where the single letters are simply the names of other folders. This regex prevents the "/c" from being added to any of the main pages, and only adds it to the pages actually located in folder "c".

However this makes it so that is excludes all strings *starting* with the letters a,c,e, etc.

How can I make it check precisely for a string; "string *is*" instead of "string *starts with*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use anchors to match precisely instead of **starts with** match.
2. You can use a character class `[acefins]` instead of alternation of single characters `(a|c|e|f|i|n|s)`

Use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:[acefins]/.*|home|mainpage1|mainpage2|mainpage3|mainpage4|mainpage5|mainpage6|mainpage7|mainpage8|mainpage9|mainpage10|mainpage11|mainpage12|mainpage13|mainpage14|mainpage15)/?$
```

Comment: Thanks but being that `mainpage1` to `mainpage15` are actually all different unique names would `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:[acefins]|home|mainpage1|mainpage2|mainpage3|mainpage4|mainpage5|mainpage6|mainpage7|mainpage8|mainpage9|mainpage10|mainpage11|mainpage12|mainpage13|mainpage14|mainpage15)/?$` then work?

Comment: Maybe it's because [acefins] are folders? Just saw your comment will try it

Comment: It's still giving me an error sadly =( The entire site

Comment: I have tested this rule in my Apache and there is no error now. You must have made a copy / paste error. Make sure there are no hidden or control character in copy/paste

Comment: I have copy/pasted clean text again in answer. Paste it directly from my  answer.

Comment: I figured out the conflict, it has to do with this in my htaccess, which I use to filter acceptable URL names: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^[\w-]{1,20}$ /e/available [L]`.  Is there any way to make it work with this code? I may need to rewrite my question.

Comment: Don't understand that since it wasn't mentioned anywhere in your question. Edit your question to provide full .htaccess and clarify the problem

Comment: Actually looking at edit I think it should be a different question since this answer was for original question that was how to change `starts with` to `is`. I have spent more than an hour trying to help you and now cannot dare to make further attempts to solve a totally different problem by overwriting my original answer.